# How to get all monday (date) for the particular year input

Tags: linux, perl

with linux command or perl ,

How to get all  monday date  for 2010

For example:

20100104  -------- this is jan monday 2010
20100111
20100118
20100125

### ----

### ---

### ---

20101206
20101213
20101220
20101227 -------- this is dec monday 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do this with DateTime in a very similar manner to Alan's solution. But it's interesting to see how you could also do it using Perl's built-in date-handling facilities.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX 'strftime';
use Time::Local;

my $ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;
my $ONE_WEEK = 7 * $ONE_DAY;

my $year = shift || 2010;

# Get Jan 1st
my $date = timelocal 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, $year - 1900;

# Get first monday
until (strftime('%a', localtime $date) eq 'Mon') {
  $date += $ONE_DAY;
}

while (strftime('%Y', localtime $date) == $year) {
  print strftime('%Y%m%d', localtime $date), "\n";
  $date += $ONE_WEEK;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;

my $year = 2010;
my $dt   = DateTime->new(
    'year'  => $year,
    'month' => 1,
    'day'   => 1,
);

# find first Monday
while ( $dt->day_name() ne 'Monday' ) {
    $dt->add( 'days' => 1 );
}

while ( $dt->year() == $year ) {
    print $dt->strftime("%Y%m%d\n");
    $dt->add( 'weeks' => 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in Perl, then give [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Calc/lib/Date/Calc.pod) a look. I'm a huge fan of Date::Calc, as its large library of functions make these kinds of calculations relatively trivial. For the problem in this question, you could do it with:

```
use Date::Calc qw(Weeks_in_Year Monday_of_Week);

$wks_in_2010 = Weeks_in_Year(2010);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $wks_in_2010; $i++) {
  ($mon_year, $mon_month, $mon_day) = Monday_of_Week($i, 2010);
  print "$mon_month/$mon_day/$mon_year\n";
}
```

Remember, [Tim Toady](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).